# How to get a RFC in XML format?

Tags: rfc

It seems Internet-Draft provides a link to download a XML file (e.g. https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31.xml), but I couldn't find a way to download a RFC (e.g. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) in XML. Is there any way to do it?
I want to re-format some RFCs to make it easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can get RFCs in a "preprocessed" XML format from https://www.rfc-editor.org/retrieve/bulk/, while the actual source of the various RFCs is at https://www.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/prerelease/. This only applies to RFC 8650 and newer though.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's not officially documented, it seems you can download some RFCs from `https://www.rfc-editor.org/authors/rfcXXXX.xml`. E.g. https://www.rfc-editor.org/authors/rfc7230.xml. Older RFCs can be found at https://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/public/rfc/xml/